# How to download SSH Private key from Azure

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops

When I created Linux Azure Scaleset the Private key was stored in cloud storage. I can see the key but don't know hot to download locally.File is at below folder in Azure Shell.

```
~/.ssh$id_rsa
```

I can vew the kile using "cat" command. Please suggests how can I download this.

Comment: If you can see it with "cat", why not just copy and paste the contents?

Comment: That didn't worked for me....I tried that pastin .pem file but it didn't allowed to connect.

Comment: The `id_rsa` file is not in `.pem` format (it's most likely in OpenSSH format); if you need PEM you'll have to convert it.

Comment: Since you can ssh into your Azure, you most probably can use sftp to download the file.  And you might need to copy the file you want somewhere else and give it proper read permissions.  Or use Azure storage disks (complicated for nothing).  OR, the easiest, `cat` the file, and copy paste it to your PC.  It is text.  This assumes you use some terminal software to ssh connect to your Azure (ex. putty, mobaxterm, some local linux, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you use the Azure Cloud Shell and want to copy the ssh key from it. When you use the Azure Cloud Shell, then you can copy the ssh key file to the Azure File Share that the cloud shell in. For example:

[image]

Then you can find the ssh key file in the File Share:

[image]

Well, at this time, there is a lot of ways to download the file. For example, the Azure CLI command [`az storage file download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_file_download). Choose the one you like.

Comment: I used cp command to copy the file in cloud drive and downloaded. Thank you for the idea